# Flutter library hosting

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I developed a flutter library for my personal use and want to host it somewhere locally like on raspberry pi I owe is that possible and if yes how can I do that? or the only way to host fullter library is through https://pub.dev ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way i can think of doing something like that is to host your own git host and leverage flutters ability to import pacakges from git urls.

in the pubspec file where you add your dependencies add something like

```
dependencies:
    kittens:
        git:
            url: git://**mylocalgithost**/munificent/kittens.git
            ref: some-branch
```

And then setup your own git server following some [guide](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-run-your-own-git-server/) for example.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using a local git host to access that package (see the answer by Emile), you can also host a local version of pub.dev itself, as it is open source: https://pub.dev/packages/pub_server.

The example section in the README describes how to set it up locally. In your Dart clients, just set the `PUB_HOSTED_URL` environment variable and Pub will try to find your package there, falling back to pub.dev.

Comment: i could not find that anywhere. Nice find.